# Textarea Tag in Perl

Tags: perl

I want to do a textarea/textbox in perl.  I have this tag but it is coming up as syntax error.

```
<textarea name="answer" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>
```

I have no idea why it is coming up, my code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use constant debug=>0;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

# Program: assignment 3
# Author: Jay
# Date: 02/2014

my $cgi= CGI->new();
my $a=$cgi->param('action');
my $num1=$cgi->param('num1');
my $num2=$cgi->param('num2');
my $num3=$cgi->param('num3');
my $num4=$cgi->param('num4');
my $hard=$cgi->param('hardware');
my $soft=$cgi->param('software');
print "$a, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4" if debug;

if ($a eq undef) {
print "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Error Logging</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error Log - IT Support</h1>
<form method=\"post\" action=/~it.jasonc/cgi-bin/assignment3.pl>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"error\">
<table>
<tr><td>Site:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"site\"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Type of Error:</td>
<td><select name=\"error\">
<option value=\"1\">Hardware</option>
<option value=\"2\">Software</option></select></td></tr>
<textarea name="answer" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>
<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit Error\"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html> "
}

if ($hard) {
  print "Go to room 1";
}
if ($soft) {
  print "Go to room 2";
}
```

I had another type as an example

```
<textarea type=\"text\" name=\"details\" value\rows="4" cols="50">
Please explain the error here!
</textarea>
```

Please help!!

Jay

Comment: You should always post the exact error you get, complete as it appears, and also mark the line number in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you quote a string using the double quote `"` character, you must escape *all* double quotes inside it. You have escaped some, but not all:

```
...
<option value=\"2\">Software</option></select></td></tr>
<textarea name="answer" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>
#              ^      ^      ^  ^      ^  ^
```

As you can see, `\"2\"` for example is escaped, but `"answer"` is not.

A better way to handle this string is to use a different quoting, such as using `qq`, which can take many different delimiters, according to your needs, for example `qq##`:

```
print qq#
<!DOCTYPE html>
....
```

You can also use a heredoc:

```
print <<EOF;
<!DOCTYPE html>
....
EOF
```

Comment: Yes I understand that of the double quote " character, but I got my friend to check the double quotes (He is an expert in perl) and he says that I have escaped all the double quotes within. @TLP

Comment: Your friend is wrong, these double quotes are not escaped. You escape characters by placing a backslash before them, so `\"` is escaped, `"` is not.

Answer (score 0):

The line `<textarea name="answer" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>` is inside a large double quoted string. If you put a double quote inside the string (a large multiline string) you have to escape it by putting a backslash before it. It's done everywhere in your code, except where your code breaks, where there are 6 unescaped double quotes.

As the following text is HTML and not perl, a syntax error is to be expected.

If you don't want to care too much about quoting double quotes (it's always easy to forget some), there is of course another way to do it (actually more than one).

You could for instance use `qq{}` instead of double quotes for perl strings. Then your code would work if quotes are escaped or not. Nothing special, it's perfectly standard perl.

Below some use exemple where I unescaped some random quote inside the HTML code (in production code I would probably unescape them all to avoid syntaxic nois).

Beside that the mere difference is the use of `qq{` after print and replacing the double quote closing string by `}`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use constant debug=>0;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

# Program: assignment 3
# Author: Jay
# Date: 02/2014

my $cgi= CGI->new();
my $a=$cgi->param('action');
my $num1=$cgi->param('num1');
my $num2=$cgi->param('num2');
my $num3=$cgi->param('num3');
my $num4=$cgi->param('num4');
my $hard=$cgi->param('hardware');
my $soft=$cgi->param('software');
print "$a, $num1, $num2, $num3, $num4" if debug;

if ($a eq undef) {
print qq{
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Error Logging</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error Log - IT Support</h1>
<form method="post" action=/~it.jasonc/cgi-bin/assignment3.pl>
<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"error\">
<table>
<tr><td>Site:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"site\"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Type of Error:</td>
<td><select name=\"error\">
<option value=\"1\">Hardware</option>
<option value=\"2\">Software</option></select></td></tr>
<textarea name="answer" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>
<tr><td colspan=\"2\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit Error\"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
}
}

if ($hard) {
  print "Go to room 1";
}
if ($soft) {
  print "Go to room 2";
}
```